# Macro Compilation error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet "b.xls" in which column A and column B have content like this:

```
Column A  Column B
C1         F1
C2         F2
C3         Z3
```

I want to copy content at location C1 , C2 , and C3 of sheet "Sheet1" of "b.xls" workbook to location F1 , F2 , Z3 of sheet "Sheet1" of workbook "a.xlsm"
I have wriiten following macro. On runing type mismatch error is displayed at point srcAddress in line of GetData.
Please help

Requirement is copy data without opening b.xls.

```
Sub Update_Data()
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim srcAddress As Range
Dim destAddress As Range
Dim r As Long   'row iterator
Dim MyPath As String

MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If
Set rngA = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)

For r = 1 To rngA.Rows.Count
Set srcAddress = Range(rngA(r).Value)
Set destAddress = Workbooks("a.xlsm").Sheets("Test_data").Range(rngB(r).Value)
GetData MyPath & "b.xls", "Sheet1", srcAddress, destAddress, True, True
'destAddress.Value = srcAddress.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `GetData` here, external procedure or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote the following code - but then read that b.xls should not be opened, so it might not be what you're after. However, if you're not allowed to open b.xls, how can you access the mapping in b.xls?

anyway, here's the code, maybe you can use parts of it. It prevents screen updating, so the user will not see that another file is opened:

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'This will prevent the workbook to be displayed during execution
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("a.xls")
    If Err.Number Then
        Err.Clear
        Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(YourPath & "a.xls")
    End If

    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each rngSource In .Range("A1").Resize(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            wsTarget.Range(rngSource.Offset(, 1).Value) = .Range(rngSource.Value).Value
        Next
    End With
    wbTarget.Save
    wbTarget.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```